# Дополнительные файлы travis для сборки

Tags: java, сборка

Есть *java* проект в котором *.properties* файлы для подключения к бд не находятся на гитхабе. Я пытаюсь скачать их с другого сайта с помощью *wget*, сборщик *gradle* все равно ругается

> No such file or directory

Вот мой *.travis.yml^*

```
language: java

sudo: required

jdk:
  - oraclejdk8

script:
   - gradle

before_script:
   - wget -P /home/travis/build/Antonerof/itevents/restservice/src/main/resources http://travis.tioo.ru/local.properties
   - psql -c 'create database itevent_test_db;' -U postgres
   - psql -c 'create database itevent_db;' -U postgres

addons:
   postgresql: "9.3"

services:
   - postgresql  

notifications:
   email: false
```

Я вижу 2 решения проблемы: скачивать с другого сайта нужные мне файлы и ложить их в нужно место и на гитхаб их добавить в другую директорию и копировать оттуда (вариант у меня тоже не заработал).
Вопрос в том как правильно копировать файлы, нужные для сборки.

Comment: А вы уверены, что этот файл вам нужен при сборке? Там вон адрес сервера БД, пароли всякие.

Comment: Может можно обойтись и без этого файла. Но данные доступа к БД и прочие удобнее хранить в таком виде.